# Aws cloudformation validate-template keeps giving error (Template format error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've been stuck with this from yesterday,
I run the below command:

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body test.json
```

(test.json is my template)
and it keeps on giving me the bellow error:

```
A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: JSON not well-formed. (line 1, column 5).
```

I even tried to test with the different aws template samples, and it still gives me the same error(with diff clolumn number).
Any solution?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The template you posted is valid but there's a syntax error in the command and it's not communicating what the problem is. Try this:

`aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://template.json`