# Template format error: unsupported structure seen in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to validate an AWS example CloudFormation template using a command like:

```
▶ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body template.yml
```

This leads to the following error message:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation:
  Template format error: unsupported structure.
```

I tried this on many templates, including example templates from the AWS documentation. So I know the templates are okay.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To the close voters... This question obviously is not off-topic for SO. AWS CloudFormation is a tool used by developers for deploying apps in the cloud; e.g. Serverless apps on Amazon; AWS CFN is a declarative DSL with programming features; SF people without programming knowledge could not answer this question and would have no use for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aws cloudformation validate-template keeps giving error (Template format error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881358/aws-cloudformation-validate-template-keeps-giving-error-template-format-error)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Apparently, the very unhelpful error message comes as a result of improper formatting in the CLI command.

The `--template-body` argument must be specified as a [file URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Thus, the correct, runnable form of the command above is:

```
▶ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://template.yml
```

See [this](https://randops.org/2016/11/11/confusing-syntax-error-with-aws-cli-and-cf-templates/) blog post for more information.

Comment: the error sys that the string "hellobucket.yml" is not a proper cloudformation template which is true ;)

Comment: My test shows that relative path to file works from the command line, as long as `file://` is included

Comment: A little clarification for future readers...  The `--template-body` CLI parameter takes a `string` argument, i.e., the template as a string.  Using the `file://` allows a local file to be supplied instead of the string.

Comment: If that is assumed to be one uri, then it would be better to show the assumed schema in the error message, that way if I see "http:// template.yml" i know that I need to change http: by file:

Comment: I wouldn't be able to figure this out without this answer! You have a special place in haven...

Comment: Same comments as @Benjamin .. You saved my day. AWS should really improve this error message. I wrote my template all over again and was still getting the error.

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't realize my tab-complete had automatically appended another `file:` prefix to the argument.

Answer (score 6):

In case, you are using windows file system, you can use like this:

```
--template-body file://c:/Windows/myfile.json
```

or

```
--template-body file://localhost/c$/Windows/myfile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
` aws cloudformation create-stack --region us-east-1 \
 --stack-name c3-app -\
 -template-body file:..//starter/c3-app.yml \
 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
`
```

the template-body must specified with file:"destination of the file from location you are now"